# Using two classes that extends a Base class with RecyclerAdapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to use a RecyclerAdapter with two viewholders.

I have a empty base class called `BaseCollectionItem`

```
/**
 * Base collection adapter item
 */
public abstract class BaseCollectionItem {
}
```

Where I want to extend `ClassA` and `ClassB` with `BaseCollectionItem`. This way for my RecyclerAdapter I can use a `List<BaseCollectionItem>` and I can add either A or B to the list to handle the different viewholder types.

But I'm running into an issue where `ClassB` already extends another class (`ClassZ`). `public class ClassB extends Class Z` so I can no longer extend `ClassB` with the `BaseCollectionItem` class.

Is there a better solution to my problem without making `BaseCollectionItem` as a wrapper class?

```
public BaseCollectionItem {
    private ClassA classA;
    private ClassB classB;
  
    public BaseCollection(ClassA classA){
       this.classA = classA;
    }

    public BaseCollection(ClassB classB){
       this.classB = classB;
    }
```

Comment: why not just use an interface ?

Comment: I don't know how thats why. Could you please give me an example?

Comment: Interesting, never knew you could use it with interfaces. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: don't really have an example to give to be honest, but your problem doesn't sound too unique, if you've already used a class, the next best way of extending upon your classes would be with interfaces. however, you should make sure that you really need the original class, but assuming that you do, then use interfaces